React Native/Expo: Cannot read property 'bubblingEventTypes' of null
I always get this error ERROR  Warning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bubblingEventTypes' of null when I add provider: {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} on my MapView
Here is my code, I use gluestack-ui as UI library that is why I'm using Box as View:
<Box className='flex-1 h-full bg-gray-500'>
  <MapView
    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  />
</Box>

I also tried:
<View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
  <MapView
    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  />
</View>

Here are the reference link that I followed: expo mapview and installation guide.
The image below is the error:

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!!!

This error appears only on iOS, I forgot to mention on my question. Thanks!

This is a bug in Expo Go! Because according to Expo documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/, MapView component is packaged with Expo Go. They have actualy highlighted that paragraph! I am about to report this as a bug.
Update:
Bug is filed against Expo for SDK 52: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/33225
Even if you use dev build, you may encounter the other bug I filed here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/33212. Unfortunately I think MapView has not been tested properly in Expo SDK 52. Expo SDK version 51 works perfectly fine for me though, and that is what I use for refactoring my production code.

Yes, you are using the expo go that is why you are facing the issue, You need to define the app.json. and make the development build not the expo go using the expo-dev-client
"ios": {
  "config": {
    "googleMapsApiKey": "API-key"
}

and for the Android
"android": {
  "config": {
    "googleMaps": {
        "apiKey": "API-key "
    }
  }
}


Btw that error appears only on iOS (I forgot to mention on my question), so it means that I won't be able to use Google Maps on iOS until I make the development build?

yes , so to work everything smoothly in your project just make the development build

As you can read in this thread https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/5049  the Expo team decided to disable support for Google Maps on iOS in ExpoGo due to the fact that people did not understand that they had to add their own API key before deploying to production.
In my case, doing a development build solved the problem.
Note! remember all the steps described here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/ This one in particular is easy to miss:

...go to the project, click Enable APIs and Services and enable the Maps SDK for iOS.



Firstly installing these three packages worked for me
npm i react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

Read my update and just try installing only this to get rid of bubblingEventTypes error:
npm i  react-native-safe-area-context


And don't forget to enter API KEY meta-data in application tag in your android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml as below.
<application
  ...
>
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_KEY_HERE" />

If you dont have API KEY you will get gray screen with a Google logo at the bottom left. This means that your mapview is working.

Updated:
Later on I removed react-native-reanimated and react-native-screens because after the build they started taking up a lot of space, their intermediates folder and .cxx folder were taking up more than +2.5GB.
After deleting react-native-reanimated and react-native-screens my project size reduced 3.3GB to 830MB.
Most probably they are no longer compatible with new gradle verisons  mine is gradle-8.11.1-bin ( as of 2024-11 ).
Now among the three I only have react-native-safe-area-context and no 'bubblingEventTypes of null error'.
Good luck.

I already did these steps, but I still got the error on iOS devices.

I was facing the same issue when i updated my expo from 50 to 52 and on my side the bug got resolved when I changed the provider from "PROVIDER_GOOGLE" to "PROVIDER_DEFAULT".
<MapView provider={PROVIDER_DEFAULT}></MapView>
version

"expo": "^52.0.18",
"react-native": "0.76.5",
"react-native-maps": "1.18.0",



I need to use Google Maps
